# Java compatible cksum function

Tags: java, checksum, crc, crc32

Is there any library/code in Java to calculate the 32-bit CRC of a stream of bytes in a way thats consistent with the cksum command in unix ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jacksum: http://www.jonelo.de/java/jacksum/index.html

```
cksum         algorithm:   POSIX 1003.2 CRC algorithm
              length:      32 bits
              type:        crc
              since:       Jacksum 1.0.0
              comment:     - under BeOS    it is /bin/cksum
                           - under FreeBSD it is /usr/bin/cksum
                           - under HP-UX   it is /usr/bin/cksum and
                             /usr/bin/sum -p
                           - under IBM AIX it is /usr/bin/cksum
                           - under Linux   it is /usr/bin/cksum
```

It's open source with GPL licence.

Comment: @palacsint: Is there a code/algo which I can use in my java program, since I do not want any 3rd party utility

Comment: Fun fact, jonelo.jacksum.algorithm.Cksum has the same interface as Java's CRC32 class but gives same result as unix cksum.

Comment: I would consult corporate counsel before using that library in company code.  The license is GPL ("copyleft"), which means you have to provide the source code of your project code to the public.  If it was the LGPL ("Lesser General Public License") you would not be compelled to provide access to your proprietary code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the CRC32 class?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html

This is the crc 32 which gzip uses.

Comment: I read online at several places that unix cksum's crc-32 algorithm is not the same as gzip's. I've not tested this, but it is likely to be true. Using 'Jacksum' (see above) works fine for me.

Comment: @Kowshik, I can verify that Java's CRC32 is NOT the same as /usr/bin/cksum

Comment: @Kowshik, check my answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

The `cksum` command on MacOS allows selecting historic algorithms and algorithm 3 is the same as `java.util.zip.CRC32`, as @RobertTupelo-Schneck pointed out.  For some reason, the more compact `CheckedInputStream` yields a different checksum.

e.g.

```
$ cksum -o 3 /bin/ls
4187574503 38704 /bin/ls
```

Same as :

```java
package com.elsevier.hmsearch.util;
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.CheckedInputStream;
import java.util.zip.Checksum;

public class Demo {

  static final String FILE = "/bin/ls";
  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Checksum cs = new CRC32();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    long totalBytes = 0;
    
    InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(FILE));
    int bytesRead = is.read(buffer);
    totalBytes += bytesRead;
    //CheckedInputStream checkedInputStream = new CheckedInputStream(is, new CRC32());
    //while ((bytesRead = checkedInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
    //  totalBytes += bytesRead;
    //}
    while (bytesRead > 0) {
      cs.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
      bytesRead = is.read(buffer);
      if (bytesRead < 1)
        break;
      totalBytes += bytesRead;
    }
    //out.printf("%d %d %s\n", checkedInputStream.getChecksum().getValue(), totalBytes, FILE);
    out.printf("%d %d %s\n", cs.getValue(), totalBytes, FILE);
  }
}
```